# Using autosuggest box in uwp, i'm getting the data from google map and i'm getting loop error

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, uwp

// The main class for the search query

```
   public class SearchQueries  
    {
        List<data> list = new List<data>();  
        string response;
```

// The method that return the list after it is set

```
        public List<data> GetData()  
        {
            return list;  
        }
```

// The method that do the searching from the google API service

```
        public async void SetData()
        {
            Search search = new Search();

            string address = search.Address;

            list.Clear();

            string dataUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyDBazIiBn2tTmqcSpkH65Xq5doTSuOo22A&input=" + address;
            string Api = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(dataUri);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            try
            {

                response = await client.GetStringAsync(Api);




            for (uint i = 0; i < jsonarray.Count; i++)
            {

                string json_string_object = jsonarray.GetObjectAt(i)["description"].ToString();


                list.Add(new data() { name = json_string_object });
            }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                ContentDialog myDlg = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
                };

                myDlg.Content = e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

// Method to get matched data

```
        public IEnumerable<data> getmatchingCustomer(string query)
        {
            return list.Where(c => c.name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1).OrderByDescending(c => c.name.StartsWith(query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        }
```

// Method for returning the SetData() method

```
        public SearchQueries()
        {
            SetData();
        }
    }
```

// The text change method of the autosuggest box

```
private async void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                if (sender.Text.Length > 1)
                {

                    var marchingData = queries.getmatchingCustomer(sender.Text);
                    sender.ItemsSource = marchingData.ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                                            sender.ItemsSource = new string[] { "No suggestion...." };
                }
            }
        }
```

[Autosuggest error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elygA.png)

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: That's the link to the error message above "Autosuggest error message"

Comment: Thank you for adding that; the message notes that there is an infinite loop or infinite recursion. Have you stepped through a debugger to find where this occurs?

Comment: I have stepped through it, I cant locate the infinite loop. it works fine whenever I set default value for the address in public async void SetData()
        { string address = "Lagos"}, but when trying to get the value from another class, it crashed and show the error messages

Comment: Everything looks fine based on your sample code. I'm guessing your actual code is quite different. Can you supply more information?

Comment: That is the real code am using, it works perfectly when I used something like this, string location = "Abuja", but this is not working, Search search = new Search(); string address = search.Address;